# How to create multiple looping background tasks in discord.py (Not rewrite)

Tags: python, discord.py, python-asyncio, background-task

I have been trying to add a looping background tasks system for my discord.py bot, but once one task starts running, it will block other tasks. I have tried searching for answer all over the place, but either they are using the rewrite version of discord.py, or they have only one task.

I am trying to make the tasks run parallelly, so all of them can run at the same time.

Here is my code:

```py
# hiding imports

class BackgroundTasksCollection:
    def __init__(self, client: discord.Client):
        self.client = client

    async def start_tasks(self):
        tasks = []
        for name in dir(self):
            if name.startswith("task_"):
                print(name)
                tasks.append(getattr(self, name))

        [await self.client.loop.create_task(task()) for task in tasks]

    # tasks
    async def task_1(self):  # only this will run because the tasks are started in alphabetical order
        await self.client.wait_until_ready()
        while not self.client.is_closed():
            await asyncio.sleep(60 * 60)

            # ...

    async def task_2(self):
        await self.client.wait_until_ready()
        while not self.client.is_closed():
            await asyncio.sleep(1)

            # ...

    async def task_3(self):
        await self.client.wait_until_ready()
        while not self.client.is_closed():
            await asyncio.sleep(30)

            # ...
```

```py
class MyClient(discord.Client):
    def __init__(self, **options):
        super().__init__(**options)
        self.tasks = BackgroundTasksCollection(self)

    async def on_ready(self):
        # ...
        await self.tasks.start_tasks()
    
    # handle message, errors, etc.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably look into tasks for tasks in the [documentation](https://discordpy-redfork.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks)

This is from the documentation linked above:

```
from discord.ext import tasks, commands

class MyCog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.index = 0
        self.bot = bot
        self.printer.start()

    def cog_unload(self):
        self.printer.cancel()

    @tasks.loop(seconds=5.0)
    async def printer(self):
        print(self.index)
        self.index += 1

    @printer.before_loop
    async def before_printer(self):
        print('waiting...')
        await self.bot.wait_until_ready()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am using a command handler of my own, so it's not a `commands.Cog`. Whould `discord.ext.task` still work in this case? Also would it be able to handle multiple tasks at the same time? I am currently using a not quite efficient work around.

Comment: you need to give it the function the tasks decorator as seen in the example answer in the documentation. You would then start it by doing self.task_name.start()

Comment: Also, if the answer I gave you is sufficient enough, please accept it.